# Retrieving public data using YouTube Analytics API

Tags: get, youtube-analytics

I would like to create a website which will allow users to input a YouTube URL, and will then generate statistics on the video or channel.

I have researched on the YouTube Analytics API, however I am encountering errors after following the https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/sample-application. I am being given a "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup." Error.

What I am after is an easy way to GET HTTP url requests, which will provide me with basic analytics (details which are public, such as likes, views etc.) So I could just execute this GET Request on the YouTube URL which is entered.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you need to follow the instructions and register your app

from https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/

```
Register your application with Google so that it can submit API requests.
```

this page has the details

https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application

> Obtaining authorization credentials
>
> Your application must have authorization credentials to be able to use the YouTube Data API. This document describes the different types
>   of authorization credentials that the Google Developers Console
>   supports. It also explains how to find or create authorization
>   credentials for your project.
>
> Create your project and select API services
>
> ```
> Go to the Google Developers Console.
> Select a project.
> In the sidebar on the left, select APIs & auth. In the list of APIs, make sure the status is ON for the YouTube Data API v3.
> In the sidebar on the left, select Credentials.
> The API supports two types of credentials. Create whichever credentials are appropriate for your project:
> OAuth 2.0: Your application must send an OAuth 2.0 token with any request that accesses private user data. Your application sends a
> ```
>
> client ID and, possibly, a client secret to obtain a token. You can
>   generate OAuth 2.0 credentials for web applications, service accounts,
>   or installed applications.
>
> ```
> Learn more
> API keys: A request that does not provide an OAuth 2.0 token must send an API key. The key identifies your project and provides API
> ```
>
> access, quota, and reports.
>
> ```
> If the key type you need does not already exist, create an API key by selecting Create New Key and then selecting the appropriate key
> ```
>
> type. Then enter the additional data required for that key type.

Comment: some other questions that may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24306611/daily-limit-for-unauthenticated-use-exceeded-continued-use-requires-signup

Comment: I have already viewed that question, and tried the suggested edit. 

The error goes away, however a blank page is displayed instead

Comment: Then I think you would need to post a little more information - read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask (Help others reproduce the problem)